# JS greeter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have problem with my html and js, i try to do a "greeter" which check inputbox if there is something it will greet you and write your name and if there is nothing it shouldnt greet you at all.. But its not working as i want. It greet you always and dont even write your name here. Can anybody help me ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>something</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="greeter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/vsb-1.4.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="c" data-title="Second example">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>TAMZ1 (Greetings)</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ui_content" role="main">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="fullName">Enter your name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullName" placeholder="e.g. J. Doe" />
            </div>

            <a data-role="button" data-icon="alert" id="greeting" data-rel="dialog" href="#grdialog">Greet me!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="dialog" id="grdialog" data-title="Greetings">
        <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Greetings!</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="greet_text"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <a data-role="button" id="back" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" href="history.back()">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(event){
    $("greeting").click(function(e){
        if ($("#fullName").val() === undefined || $("#fullName").val() === "")        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You did not fill your name!");
        }
    else{
            $("#greet_text").text("Greetings, " + $("#fullName").val() + '!');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a greeting element, not an element with an id

```
$("greeting").
```

needs to be

```
$("#greeting").
```